# Secondary Tiles deep-links not working

Tags: windows-phone-7

I use secondary tiles in my app and link them to an internal page (not to the main page) for example, I use the following deep-link:

ShellTile.Create(new Uri(string.Format("/UpdatePage.xaml?Id={0}&ChosenDate={1}&RecordNumber={2}", this.obj.Id, this.obj.ChosenDate, this.obj.RecordNumber), UriKind.Relative), dateShellTimeData);

Now, each time I click on one of the live tiles, the splash screen appear for a while and then the home screen appears again (it seems because of an exception).

(I use schedule agent in my app).

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code as it works for me...

```
ShellTile.Create(new Uri(string.Format("/UpdatePage.xaml?Id="+this.obj.Id+"&ChosenDate="+this.obj.ChosenDate+"&RecordNumber="+this.obj.RecordNumber), UriKind.Relative), dateShellTimeData);
```